# Avaudioplayer how to stop playing object from other controller

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have `firstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. In both controllers I can tap play button and melody will play. So when I tap play button in 1 controller and then go to 2controller and tap other play button 2 melodies will play together. So my question is how to stop 1st melody from 1st controller when I tap play button in 2nd controller. Thank you!

In firstViewController `viewdidload`

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundURL_ = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AVAudioPlayer *first = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL_ error:nil];
[first prepareToPlay];
```

The same in `secondViewcontroller` the same but second instead of first

When I pressed the button:

```
[first play]
```

Comment: Show your code, and put a better title on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one instantiation of custom object that contains the AVAudioPlayer and methods associated with the player and then create a pointer for that object in both of your views.

If you would like to instantiate your AVAudioPlayer from within the AppDelegate you will have to first set up your AVAudioPlayer and assign it to a property of your AppDelegate.

From within your View Controllers, accessing any property of your App Delegate is easy, just write:

```
AppNameAppDelegate *ad = (AppNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

followed by:

```
localAVAudioPlayerInstance = ad.audioPlayer;
```

Let me know if you'd like more detailed instructions.

Comment: But it will play in second view again

Comment: If you have only one instantiation of this object, this object is essentially the brain. You access this one instance of the object from many places and control all audio calls through this one object so you have to write it to be self checking.

Comment: Do you have a code that I can check please? I actually want to see how you declare one avaudioplayer object in app delegate and then access it in other controllers!

Comment: Thank you, you helped me. I tried to resolve this problem about four days. @achi